# Locating Postgres database

Tags: command-line, postgresql

I am working on this new ubuntu 12.04 server and I need to work on the Postgres database which is PostGIS enabled. The problem is I am not sure how to locate the database using command line.

It is already installed on the server. I just need to locate it. How do I locate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the file `/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf` and in the section under the title "FILE LOCATIONS".  For instance:

```
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main'
```

is what I have.

Comment: Alternately you can connect to it and run `SHOW data_directory;`